No output device, until I plug in an AUX cable
A little while ago I messed something up while inside my audio system settings GUI (Using KDE Plasma on Debian). I can not recall exactly what I did, but I pressed some button while inside that menu that removed my only sound output. This change was unfortunately persistent across reboots.
The good news is, I can add an output again by inserting an AUX cable. I then have sound through my headphones. Also, after I remove the headphones, the output remains without problem. However, this means that I have to replug my AUX cable to get an output device every time I reboot.
Now for my investigations: In the no-output state, when I run pulseaudio --kill in my command line, PulseAudio is immediately restarted, prompting a pop-up saying No output device. When the AUX is inserted the first time, a similar pop-up shows Built-in Audio Analog Stereo, with an image of a sound-card. This is all shown in this video recorded during a first-time AUX replug. I also ran pacmd list-sinks before and after the replug. This is shown in the video, and the output from that command is copied below:
❯ # Before the AUX replug:
❯ pacmd list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
        name: <auto_null>
        driver: <module-null-sink.c>
        flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
        state: SUSPENDED
        suspend cause: IDLE
        priority: 1000
        volume: front-left: 65453 / 100% / -0.03 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
                balance 0.00
        base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        volume steps: 65537
        muted: no
        current latency: 0.00 ms
        max request: 344 KiB
        max rewind: 344 KiB
        monitor source: 1
        sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right
                     Stereo
        used by: 0
        linked by: 0
        configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
        module: 14
        properties:
                device.description = "Dummy Output"
                device.class = "abstract"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card"
❯ # I will now insert an AUX cable, which for some reason ends up adding an output
❯ pacmd list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 1
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
        state: SUSPENDED
        suspend cause: IDLE
        priority: 9039
        volume: front-left: 72090 / 110% / 2.48 dB,   front-right: 72090 / 110% / 2.48 dB
                balance 0.00
        base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        volume steps: 65537
        muted: no
        current latency: 0.00 ms
        max request: 0 KiB
        max rewind: 0 KiB
        monitor source: 2
        sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right
                     Stereo
        used by: 0
        linked by: 0
        configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
        card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
        module: 6
        properties:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = "ALC257 Analog"
                alsa.id = "ALC257 Analog"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "0"
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xa133c000 irq 148"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "8086"
                device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
                device.product.id = "9dc8"
                device.product.name = "Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller"
                device.form_factor = "internal"
                device.string = "front:0"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
                device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
                device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
                device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
                device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        ports:
                analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
                analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
        active port: <analog-output-speaker>


Are anyone able to identify why I have to replug an AUX to make this output device (or "sink") available? Or perhaps have any idea how I caused this problem by some key/mouse button press inside the GUI audio menu?

What profile do you have selected in pavucontrol > "Configuration"? Is this pipewire-pulse or the original pulseaudio?

I had "Analog Stereo Input". Changing to "Analog Stereo Duplex" has the same effect as replugging an AUX cable, i.e. fixing the issue! So I suppose that replugging simply had the effect of changing the profile, and that I somehow managed to change my default profile at a point. If you want, you can tell me to change my profile in pavucontrol in a proper reply, and I will mark it as the answer ^_^ Bonus points for saying how to change the default profile :D

Update: I can also change this profile in the system settings under Hardware->Audio - no need to install pavucontrol. Additionally, when I changed the profile manually (as opposed to the AUX replug trick), the change was persistent automatically. So the complete fix ended up being (a) open system settings, (b) open the "Audio" section under "Hardware" (using KDE Plasma), (c) change the profile to "Analog Stereo Duplex".
Thanks a lot - this has been quite annoying for a while, but within a day of asking here the problem was fixed ^_^
